# Finding set of numbers such the following equation has a real solution

Tags: equation-solving

I have a set of numbers, for instance:

$ \lbrace 49, 25, 26, 5, 21, 47, 24 \rbrace
$

And I want to find numbers $a,b,c,d$ such

the following equation has real solution

```
With[{r = 0.7}, 
list2 /. Assuming[Element[list2, Reals],
FindInstance[
Mean[list1] == Mean[list2] && 
Simplify[Variance[list1] == Variance[list2]] && 
Simplify[Correlation[list1, list2] == r], {l, m, t}]]]
```

where

```
list1 = {49, 25, 26, 5, 21, 47, 24}

list2 = {a, b, c, d, l, m, t}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Reals* domain with *FindInstance*. The problem then is that the running time is very long, probably because the equation system is under-determined. Since you have 3 equations, leaving 7-3=4 free variables does the job; here I just set the first $n=7-3=4$ variables (a,b,c,d) equal to their counterparts in *list1*.

```
list1 = {49, 25, 26, 5, 21, 47, 24};
μ = Mean[list1];
v = Variance[list1];
r = .7;
list2 := {a, b, c, d, l, m, t};
n = Length[list1] - 3;

FindInstance[
 Take[list1, n] == Take[list2, n] &&
  μ == Mean[list2] &&
  v == Variance[list2] &&
  Correlation[list1, list2] == r,
 list2, Reals]

  ListPlot[Transpose@{list1, list2 /. % // First}]
```

output is

```
{{a -> 49., b -> 25., c -> 26., d -> 5., l -> 17.8305, m -> 28.2102, 
  t -> 45.9593}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]